# Java -- MongoDB collection.find() by _id

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, mongodb-query

I am trying to get an element from a collection by using his unique _id, but I can not find how.

This is my code

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DB");
MongoCollection<Document> collection =   database.getCollection("COLL");
```

If I query my db with

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("info.i0","0");
Document myDoc = collection.find(query).first();
System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());
```

I get as output

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "560ea3f205240f065a3e9d19" }, "name" : "MongoDB", "type" : "database", "count" : 1, "info" : { "i0" : "0", "i1" : "1", "i2" : "2", "i3" : "3", "i4" : "4", "i5" : "5", "i6" : "6", "i7" : "7", "i8" : "8", "i9" : "9" } }
```

But If I try

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("_id.$oid","560ea3f205240f065a3e9d19");
Document myDoc = collection.find(query).first();
System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());
```

I get a Null pointer exception, as myDoc is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$oid` is there only to [preserve BSON representation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

It only has meaning to MongoDB internal JSON parsers.

You only have to use `_id` in your query:

`BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("_id",new ObjectId("560ea3f205240f065a3e9d19"));`

Also, note that the `_id` field is of type `ObjectId` and not `String`.

You will have to wrap it in an `ObjectId` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I was using ("_id","ObjectId(\"560ea3f205240f065a3e9d19\")"); that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good news is there is no issue in your query, but your document does not look correct, How you able to insert filed name start with $ ?

**Documents have the following restrictions on field names:**

The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array.
The field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
The field names cannot contain the dot (.) character.
The field names cannot contain the null character.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON (scala) : `Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> "560ea3f205240f065a3e9d19"))`